# Mixed Variable Stacked Barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to produce a GGPlot stacked barplot with variables on the horizontal axis, yet some variables have different responses.

Some variables are 'Y/N' responses. Some variables are 'Old/Young'. And some of the variables are a Likert scale of  0-5.

Therefore, I would like to plot these in a stacked barplot form, with  each variable type encoded with a different colour palette, and with a legend reflecting the different palettes/variable types.

I wondered if someone could help with this, please? Would be greatly appreciated.

```
X1<-c("N","N","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","N","N","N","N","Y","N","N","Y","N","N","N","Y","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","N","N","N","Y","N","N","Y","N","Y","Y","N","Y","N","N")
X2 <-c("N","N","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","N","N","N","N","Y","N","N","Y","N","N","N","Y","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","N","N","N","Y","N","N","Y","N","Y","Y","N","Y","N","N")
X3<-c(1,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,0,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
X4 <-c("YouNg","Old","Old","YouNg","Old","Old","Old","YouNg","YouNg","YouNg","Old","Old","Old",
       "Old","Old","Old","Old","YouNg","Old","Old","Old","YouNg","YouNg","Old","Old","Old",
       "Old","Old","Old","Old","Old","Old","Old","YouNg","Old","YouNg","Old","YouNg","Old",
       "Old","YouNg","Old","YouNg","YouNg","Old","Old","Old","YouNg","Old","Old","Old","YouNg", "Old", "Old")

Y <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3, X4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would to use the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- Y |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var")

ggplot(dat, aes(y = var)) +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("X1", "X2")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent", guide = guide_legend(order = 3))+ 
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("X3")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("X4")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", guide = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Depending on what you want to achieve there are three arguments to consider:

- Use `position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)` in `geom_bar` to reverse the order of the stack
- To reverse the order of the fill colors use `direction=-1` in `scale_fill_xxx`
- Finally, if you want to reverse the order in the legend use `reverse=TRUE` in `guide_legend`.

The example code below uses all three, i.e.

- the bars run from 0 on the left to 4 on the right.
- the fill colors are reversed so that 0 is now assigned "pink"  and 4 the "green" color
- and finally the order in the legend is reversed.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y = var)) +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("X1", "X2")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent", guide = guide_legend(order = 3))+ 
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("X3")), aes(fill = value), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(order = 2, reverse = TRUE), direction = -1) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("X4")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", guide = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. Looks very good to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Stefan. This works perfectly for me. Thanks again. However, my vertical axis gets alphabetised in descending order. I wondered if you knew how to ensure that the axes would be grouped in a particular order? Say for example, I wanted X1 below X4, or something along those lines.

Comment: Sure. Option 1 would be to convert the variable mapped on `y` to a factor with levels set in your desired order. Option 2 would be to set the order via the `limits` argument of the scale, i.e. try `scale_y_discrete(limits = c("X2", "X3", "X1", "X4"))`to move X1 below X4

Comment: Thanks Stefan. The more I think about it, is it possible to group by palette?

Comment: Thanks Stefan, the scale_y_discrete works perfect. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Hi @Stefan. Sorry to bother you again. Would it be possible for you to show how to manually order the stack fill? For example, X3 going from left to right in ascending order, with 0 as the first value?

Comment: Hej EB. I just added an edit to show you the three arguments to consider when reversing the order of the stack or the colors or the order of the legend.